# cin causes runtime error

Tags: c++, runtime-error, cin

Here's the problem https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/extra-long-factorials
Here's my code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int product[200];
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)product[i] = 0;
    product[0] = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        int a[200], res[200];
        for (int j = 0; j < 200; j++)a[j] = 0, res[j] = 0;
        int n = i;
        int k = 0;
        while(n != 0){
            a[k] = n % 10;
            n = n / 10;
            k++;
        }
        int at[200][200];
        for (int p = 0; p < 200; p++){
            for (int h = 0; h < 200; h++){
                at[p][h] = 0;
            }
        }
        int carry = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < 200; x++){
            for (int d = 0; d < 200; d++){
                at[x][x+d] = ((product[d] * a[x]) % 10) + carry;
                carry = (product[x] * a[d]) / 10;
            }
        }
        int carry2, temp;
        for (int u = 0; u < 200; u++){
            temp = 0;
            for (int e = 0; e < 200; e++){
                temp += at[e][u];
            }
            temp = (temp + carry2);
            carry2 = temp/10;
            res[u] = temp %10;
            product[u] = res[u];
        }
    }
    int f = 0;
    for (; f < 200; f++){
        if(product[200-f-1] != 0)break;
    }
    for (; f < 200; f++){
        cout << product[200-f-1];
    }       
    return 0;
}
```

It runs fine on gcc on my mac and gives a correct answer. However it gives a runtime error on the online judge as well as ideone.
I've debugged the code and the error is caused by `cin >> n;` It runs fine without it and gives a correct answer (which is 1). The test input that caused the error is 25 so it's not a big number. I dont know exactly what's the problem or how is it causing the error. Thank you.

Comment: Maibe the error is cause because n is the name of two variables (even if they are in two distinct privacy levels)

Comment: Have you tried running it under a debugger? It should tell you roughly where the problem is, even if it runs fine without it.

Comment: `carry2` is not initialized

Comment: changed the name of n, same problem. and carry2 is initialized.

Comment: @user3740884 No, it's not initialised, and you're using it before you've assigned a value to it.

Comment: No, it's not. At the first usage `carry2` is unitialized. At least in the code you provide in your question and even after your edit.

Comment: Ok I've assigned to a value before using it and still got the same problem

Comment: These aren't answers. These are comments on your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the problem:

`at[x][x+d] = ...`

because both `x` and `d` run from `0` to `200`, but `at` is an array on the stack, with size: `[200][200]` so obviously `x+d` will overwrite the code coming after the array declaration.

This is a classical buffer overflow :)

(Obviously, initializing `carry2` won't hurt either, but not doing that will not give the core dump at `0x0`, just some unexpected behaviour)

Comment: I noticed it when i was writing the code but it ran so i didnt bother. any ideas how to fix it ?

Comment: Increase the array size to 400 ... or use std::vector of std::vector of int ?

Comment: It worked. However i want to know why g++ ran it fine.

Comment: @user3740884 In standardese speak it is undefined behavior, running fine is one manifestation of undefined behavior. In practice you access memory after `at`. If there happens to be memory you can write to everything is good (except you corrupt something, possibly the memory that `cin` needed). If there isn't it crashes. Seems like ideone and the online judge had some memory there that couldn't be written to (reduces stack size to safe memory?), your system doesn't have that issue.

Comment: You mentioned that you run it on a MAC, I'm really curious whether on MACs the values declared on stack contains some extra buffering around them, or they are put somewhere else that it does mix with your code...

Comment: Thanks everyone that really helped :)